# How to show an empty view when using PagedListAdapter with LiveData?

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

Usually on a `RecyclerView` I show an empty view when there are no items on the `RecyclerView` and since I control all updates to the `RecyclerView` via the `notify` methods then that is pretty simple but with `PagedListAdapter` updates just seem to happen on the background, so how can I hide or show my empty view?

For example, if I call `deleteItem()` on my `Room DB`, the `PagedListAdapter` will be updated on its own without me calling `notifyItemDeleted` but if it was the last item on the list, how does my code know to show the empty view? I could query the DB each time an action happens for the count but that seems wasteful. Is there a better way?

Comment: Create a separate adapter for empty views.. easiest approach... Others are complicated for `pagedList`

Comment: `PagedListAdapter` does not update on its own. As far as I know it accept new `PagedList` through `.submitList()` method. Therefore you can check emptyness in the same `LiveData` observer, or you can choose to override `.submitList()` method of your `PagedListAdapter` and check list emptyness there.

Comment: @SanlokLee you appear to be correct, if you want make an answer for it, I will gladly mark it as correct.

Comment: You can refer from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61845719/7438254

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you can test emptiness of the list in the same `LiveData` observer you use for `.submitList()`.

**Java Example:**

I am assuming you are following something similar to [this snippet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedListAdapter.html#submitList(android.arch.paging.PagedList%3CT%3E)) found in the `PagedListAdapter` document. I am simply adding emptiness check to that sample code.

```
class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onCreate(savedState);
        MyViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.user_list);
        UserAdapter<User> adapter = new UserAdapter();
        viewModel.usersList.observe(this, pagedList -> {
            // Check if the list is empty
            updateView(pagedList.size());
            adapter.submitList(pagedList));

            pagedList.addWeakCallback(null, new PagedList.Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onChanged(int position, int count) {
                    updateView(pagedList.size())
                    // updateView(adapter.getItemCount())
                }

                ...
            }
        }
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void updateView(int itemCount) {
        if (itemCount > 0) {
            // The list is not empty. Show the recycler view.
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            // The list is empty. Show the empty list view
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }
}
```

**Kotlin Example:**

The above Java example is actually just a Java translation of Kotlin example I found in this [Android Paging codelab](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-paging/blob/solution/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/codelabs/paging/ui/SearchRepositoriesActivity.kt).

Comment: unfortunately in my case, value of pagedList.size() always shows 0.
Is there any way to solve?

Comment: @Omi You are correct that `PagedList.size()` can sometimes be 0 when there is in fact data. Let me fix the answer so that it can check for adapter size when the `PagedList` gets updated.

Comment: Best of luck bro. Hopefully you will able to find the exact solution we are looking for

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best solution, but you can give it a try

```
    myViewModel.getMyPagedList().observe(MainActivity.this, items -> {
        myPagedListAdapter.submitList(items);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (myPagedListAdapter.getItemCount() == 0) {
                    runOnUiThread(() -> {
                        emptyTextView.setText("Empty");
                        emptyTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    });
                    // The Runnable will be re-executed (repeated) as long as if condition is true
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
                } else
                    emptyTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        };
        // trigger first time
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    });
```