# Doesn't getting itemCount of PagedListAdapter after submitList

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-paging

I'm implemented ***paging feature*** based on `PagedListAdapter` and I've been checked that works fine. I try implementation to feature as ***If ListAdapter items are empty then showing EmptyHolder***. I have tried that based on `commitCallback` after called `submitList` as follows code.

## Question

> Why has PagedListAdapter item count shows as 0 even though the response contains items? How to solve this problem?

## FooDataSource

```
private suspend fun loadItems(beforeId: String) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    getFooUseCase(beforeId)
}

override fun loadInitial(
    params: LoadInitialParams<String>,
    callback: LoadInitialCallback<String, Foo>
) {
    launch {
        loadItems(null)
            .run {
                Timber.d("loadInitial : ${list.size}") // onResponse : 20
                callback.onResult(list, null, beforeId)
            }
    }
}
```

## FooListFragment

```
observe(fooList) { items ->
    // items.size or loadedCount always 0
    fooAdapter.submitList(items) {
        //fooAdapter.itemCount, fooAdapter.currentList.size or loadedSize
        //always 0...
        if(fooAdapter.itemCount == 0) {
            //show EmptyHolder
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`PagedList.BoundaryCallback` have `onZeroItemsLoaded` method for handle empty initial load

```
val livedPageList = LivePagedListBuilder(sourceFactory, config)
        .setBoundaryCallback(object: PagedList.BoundaryCallback<YourItem>() {
            override fun onZeroItemsLoaded() {
                super.onZeroItemsLoaded()
                // Handle empty initial load here
            }

            override fun onItemAtEndLoaded(itemAtEnd: YourItem) {
                super.onItemAtEndLoaded(itemAtEnd)
                // Here you can listen to last item on list
            }

            override fun onItemAtFrontLoaded(itemAtFront: YourItem) {
                super.onItemAtFrontLoaded(itemAtFront)
                // Here you can listen to first item on list
            }
        })
        .build()
```

You can check complete answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55649243/5695091)